# vim - Auto-indent after opening multiple lines ('2o')

Tags: vim

At the moment if I use 'o', then the inserted line is auto-indented properly. Should I do '2o' however (followed by esc to realise it), I'm of course not in insert mode and the cursor is unindented. This is quite tedious.

How am I best to deal with this problem? Ideally I'd like to end up correctly indented and in insert mode after '2o' (or some equally convenient combination) - no doubt this is a problem others have encountered and solved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just hit `<Enter>` after `o`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what behavior you want in general. I would do what romainl suggested. You might also try this:

```
:set indentexpr=indent(prevnonblank(v:lnum-1))
```

That will cause any line you add to be indented the same as the previous non-blank line.